# Clone Azure key vault from one azure account to another account

Tags: azure-keyvault

I want to clone Azure Key vaults from account `A` to account `B`.

Can someone guide me in how to clone the key vault? Is there any procedure for it?

Or, otherwise, how could I recreate the key vault in the account `B` manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed using ARM templates by removing secrets from it, secrets has to be added manually

Answer (score 0):

You can move resource across subscirption under same tenant , The target subscription must exist and in enabled state.

You can refer this [**Checklist before moving resources**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#checklist-before-moving-resources)

There are some important steps to do before moving a resource. By verifying these conditions, you can avoid errors.

> The source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same
> Active Directory tenant.